# Mutable state in a play controller, threadsafety with Actors?

Tags: scala, playframework, actor

If you have a mutable state to maintain in a play controller in a thread-safe manner, do you generally reach out to Actors in doing so? for e.g.

```
object Application extends Controller {
   var users = Set[String]()
    def addUser(username: String) = Action { request =>
        users += username 
    }
}
```

so to make it thread safe Actor code may look something like

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
    var users = Set[String]()
    def receive = {
      case AddUser(user) =>{
        users += user
      }
}
```

It feels like an overkill to use Actor just for maintaining a shared state in a threadsafe manner but if not Actors, what other approach you may opt for global threadsafe like cache?

Comment: someone posted a comment about using a val of mutable.Set. Mistakenly I deleted his comment. can that user post it again? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those two options are not Thread-safe :

```
var users = Set[String]()
val users = collection.mutable.Set()
```

If you want basic collections to be thread-safe, Scala provide a Synchronized trait.
(but please don't do that, this solution doesn't scale and will break Play performances)

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
new HashSet[String]() with SynchronizedSet[String]
```

I think the best available option to you is to create an Actor. Actor are really lightweight, you should not fear about that.